# react-native iOS new scheme error: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperClient

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, flipper

I added a new build configuration, `Dev.Debug` to my react-native project in xcode, duplicating the existing `Debug` configuration, and also added a corresponding scheme for the new configuration.

Now when I attempt to run the project with the new scheme I get the error:

`Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperClient`

Running the scheme that I duplicated works fine - the app installs, launches, and functions normally.

Is there any more configuration required after adding a new debug scheme?

Answer (score 7):

I found that I needed to modify my podfile as follows:

```
...

target 'MyApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  # Add the project and build configurations
  project 'MyApp',
    'Dev.Debug' => :debug, # '{Build Configuration name}' => :{debug or release}
    'Debug' => :debug,
    'Dev.Release' => :release,
    'Release' => :release
...

use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.126.0', configurations: ['Debug', 'Dev.Debug']}) # Add the Build Configuration name (not scheme name)

...
```

Comment: 8 hours of searching and this is what solved it for me. Thanks! I ended up not declaring the flipper versions in the end, so it looked like this for me: `use_flipper!({ configurations: ['Debug', 'Dev.Debug'] })`

Answer (score 5):

In my case I updated to `react native: 0.70.*` and Flipper to version 174 and had this error. Downgrading Flipper to 163 fixed the issue for me.

More info here: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/4278

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of React Native, `AppDelegate.mm` has replaced the legacy Flipper initialisation code with `RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);` and I had forgotten to do so. This caused the issue for me. Fixing it solved the issue. See https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ for the diffs.

Answer (score 1):

i downgraded from:

```
-    "react-native-flipper": "^0.212.0",
+    "react-native-flipper": "^0.164.0",
```

now both `debug` and `archive` work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was solved by installing the proper version of the `react-native-flipper` npm package.

I could see in the `Podfile.lock` and `gradle.properties` the binary Flipper version was 0.125.0 so I did a `yarn add react-native-flipper@0.125.0` instead of the default version, and now I can build again :)

Comment: can simply disabling flipper work ? I got this error when I used react-native-svg a little older version

Answer (score 0):

For react-native 0.72, you should re-install your pods with

```
PRODUCTION=1 bundle exec pod install
```

To remove Flipper from the Release build. Flipper can't be built in Release mode, Flipper is going to be deprecated in 0.73 and it will be removed in 0.74.

Big thanks to [cipolleschi](https://github.com/cipolleschi)

Answer (score -2):

Change XCode Build Configuration from Release => Debug fix this error for me